# What email service provider can I connect a .net mail client to?

Tags: asp.net, email

Every month I have to email out links to demo music tracks that I make. I have like 30 labels and it takes me ages to write out an email to each one. I dont want to purchase my own domain name yet so is there a free email provider that I can sign up to that will allow me to use .net library to automatically send out messages?

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty. [www.gmail.com](http://www.gmail.com) is one. There is no real difference between connecting with a .net mail client and any email program such as firebird or outlook.

Comment: so how to I connect to it and automate a mail shot?

Comment: @Pete2k have a look at this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would use a newsletter tool like mailchimp or madmini.

Answer (score 0):

Although using C# is by far more flexible, did you try Mailmerge in [Office](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/word-mail-merge-a-walk-through-the-process-HA001034920.aspx) or [OpenOffice](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Writer_Guide/Using_Mail_Merge)?